# Parse.com as backend for iOS app

Tags: ios, asp.net, parse-platform, pdf-generation

I need to create backend app for iOS application.
The conditions are as follows:

- Store data in the database;
- Sending push notification;
- Generating PDF on the server.

  1. Working with database is familiar to me and it works well.
  2. To send a notifications whether it is possible to use [Parse Notifications](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/iOS) or need to use some Apple service, only?
  3. I'd like to make a web service in ASP.NET which will generate a PDFs. I'm afraid that Parse.com does not support [hosting for ASP.NET web apps](https://www.parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#hosting). What do I do in this case?
     Do you have to use other tools, like Express.js framework (with which I am not familiar with)?

Comment: Well, what did you do for that? Do you think we will do all this work for you?

Comment: No, it's not that like. I do not need nobody to do the program, but the idea what the tools should I use. Is that a problem?
Unfortunately Parse.com has terminated its support forum and redirect all developers here on SO. So that I unfortunately am forced to seek help here...

Comment: If Parse is sending people to StackOverflow for `How To` information and tech support then don't use their service. Any company that cannot provide that info up-front is not a good choice and may not survive long-term.

Comment: Looks like parse still has a Google group. Your question would be more on topic there.

Comment: @RoboticCat Parse is owned by Facebook, I don't think they're going anywhere. There are tons of docs on their website that can be used to figure out some of the things the OP needs to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse can do almost all of the things that you mentioned.

1. For storing data in the database, go through [this](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#dotnet_guide) tutorial.
2. For push notifications, go through [this](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/.NET) tutorial.
3. For generating a PDF, you're going to have to do it on the client side. After some quick research I found [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf) as a viable option.

Comment: just found out that Parse supports  this Parse.Cloud.httpRequest. So I was thinking t osend request to some 3rd party service like pdfcrowd to generate  PDF. Still not sure if this is work. (generating PDFs Client side is not the option since clients are with mobile devices and I dont want load on them

Comment: That sounds like it could work. The tutorials will definitely help guide you in the right direction.